# component option "computed" should be an object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am getting this error in Vue v2.4.1. and I'm not sure what it means:

> [Vue warn]: component option "computed" should be an object.

My code looks like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            bookings: [],
            games: [],
            slots: [],
            startTime: {
                time: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            }
        };
    },
    components: {
        'date-picker': myDatepicker,
        'reserved' : Reserved
    },
    ready() {
        this.prepareComponent();
    },
    mounted() {
        this.prepareComponent();
    },
    methods: {
        prepareComponent() {
            this.getGames();
            this.getSlots();
            this.getBookings(this.startTime.time);
        },
        onDateChange(){
        },
        formatSlot(slot){
        },
        getGames(){
        },
        getSlots() {
        },
        getBookings(date){
        },
        isReserved(gameId,slotId){
        },
        getReservedBooking(gameId,slotId){
        },
        isPastTime(time, date){
        },
        getUrl(date,slot_id,game_id){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your project (not in the code you've shared) you are creating a Vue instance and passing a `computed` option that is not an object.

Comment: You mean I have made computed: {} instead of computed(){} ?

Comment: It should be `computed: {}`. So if you have `computed() {}`as one of your Vue component options, that's your problem.

Comment: @thanksd alright thank you so much. I will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because, somewhere in your project, you are defining a Vue component with the `computed` option set to something that is not an object.

Check your project for any instances where this is happening and replace the value of the `computed` option with an object.

Most likely, you have mistakenly written `computed() { ... }` instead of `computed: { ... }`.

[Here is the basic example of a computed property from the documentation.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example)